# Loading Tensorflow Model From TFHUB into BigQuery

Tags: tensorflow, google-bigquery

I'm trying to load https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder-lite/2 into BigQuery.

I've downloaded the model and have moved these files into a cloud storage bucket:

```
rwxr-x---@  3  jeffjames  staff       96 May 31  2018 assets
-rw-r-----@  1 jeffjames  staff  1565708 May 31  2018 saved_model.pb
drwxr-x---@  4 jeffjames  staff      128 May 31  2018 variables
```

Then, I attempt to create the model in BigQuery:

```
CREATE MODEL jeff_james.uselite
 OPTIONS(MODEL_TYPE='TENSORFLOW',
         MODEL_PATH="gs://my_bucket_path/*")
```

Note the files are all in the root of the bucket.

But I'm getting this error:

```
Error when loading TensorFlow SavedModel with tag set 'serve': Could not find meta graph def matching supplied tags: { serve }. To inspect available tag-sets in the SavedModel, please use the SavedModel CLI: `saved_model_cli`
```

However when I attempt to use the saved_model_cli, I get no useful information:

```
The given SavedModel contains the following tag-sets:
```

Can this model actually be loaded into BigQuery? https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-ml/docs/reference/standard-sql/bigqueryml-syntax-create-tensorflow#limitations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this model can't currently be loaded into BigQuery.  I downloaded and looked at the meta_graph_def for the model.  It doesn't define any tag set.  It does define two signatures "default" and "spm_path".

Generally, BigQuery expects a tag set named "serve" and a signature named "serving_default", which are the usual settings for most TensorFlow trainers.

Side note, the model appears to be trained with TensorFlow version "1.8.0-rc1", which is a 2.5 year old version.

Comment: Thanks @Chris Meyers - that was helpful.